# Is duplicate title tags an issue when they're redirected?

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, 301-redirect, duplicate-content, title

According to Google Webmaster Tools, I have a number of duplicate title tags. This happens because my products all have two URLs: `/products/product` and `/product/product-category/product`.
`/products/produc`t is redirecting to `/products/product-category/product`, so should I worry about all the duplicate title tags? Does it matter what content is on a page that is redirected?

Answer (score 2):

Google Webmasters provides the details of the Duplicated titles present for your site.We need to download those information.Then We need to use rel="canonical" in the suitable https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html way to solve this issue.

Else the Google treats it duplicate content https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content is explained clearly here with pictures.[image]

In E-Commerce site when similar products are repeated this issue occurs.At that time rel="canonical" is used in the main page. So that Google robots treats it as main page and other similar pages are following it.http://www.goinflow.com/duplicate-content-ecommerce-seo/ . This solves the Duplicate Title tag issue & Duplicate content issue also.For dynamic content this would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325842/how-to-prevent-duplicate-title-tags-on-dynamic-content helpful.

And also minimize **Redirection** as far as possible because it slows down site speed.(https://varvy.com/pagespeed/minimize-redirects.html). Because Page Speed is one of important ranking factor.(https://moz.com/blog/how-website-speed-actually-impacts-search-ranking) . So we need to think of Page Speed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Its won't be any issue, but I believe instead of using 301 redirection you need to use canonical tag to avoid such duplicity issues. 301 redirection work best at domain level